# AngularJS ui-select: option not added when typed fully

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using angular ui-select and I want to allow the user to select an option using auto-complete, but also allow them to type in custom options.

I've configured the control with tagging enabled and no tagging labels as follows:

```
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="false" ng-model="colors" theme="bootstrap" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
        {{color}}
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here's an example plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YW7WloZCds1XIOS6UsNs?p=preview

The problem is that when you type in a word that exists in the available colors and press enter, that option does not become selected.

In the plunkr, you can see this if you type *Blue* and press enter.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug related to using `tagging-label="false"`. It works correctly when removing this option, or perhaps you can find a workaround.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/770

Comment: +1 for verifying I'm not going crazy. I'll have a play and see if there's a workaround before accepting this answer.

Comment: Cool, I didn't have time to try anything really so hopefully there's something simple. Good luck.